Looker Studio Custom Map Visualization Breaks After Reload
I'm currently working on an online dashboard in Google Looker Studio, with BigQuery as the database backend.
One of the visualizations involves displaying polygons on a map, which had been working perfectly in the past. Recently, however, I've encountered instability: after configuring everything, the visualization displays correctly at first, but breaks once the dashboard is reloaded.
Here are the specifics of the issue:
The problem occurs when I use a dimension to assign colors to the map.
Initially, the legend doesn't display (it used to work, and I have previous dashboards to prove this).
Upon reloading the dashboard, the entire visualization fails to render.
Strangely, if I assign a metric for the same purpose (e.g., to color polygons), the visualization seems to work as expected.
I've checked the data in BigQuery, including the geometry column, and everything seems fine. I've also tested exporting the same data to other platforms like BQ Geo Viz, and the polygons render correctly there. This leads me to believe that the issue lies within Looker Studio itself.
I suspect either a recent update to Looker Studio may have introduced a bug, or there’s some cache-related issue preventing proper rendering.
Has anyone experienced this issue recently, or does anyone have insights into potential solutions?
Here’s a link to a sample dashboard showcasing the problem: Sample Dashboard.
Notes:

The Sample Dashboard contains two pages, the second one has only 2 rectangles which don't represent any effort in processing but still get the same output.
The data for both visualizations is based on tables having GEOGRAPHY datatype, even the second map has different columns with GEOGRAPHY datatype produce by WKT and GEOJSON format to verify if the issue wasn't related to the format. Here you find the WKT for both of the retangles of the second page so you can do your own checks POLYGON 1:POLYGON((-94.136361 41.954384, -94.136361 41.964085, -94.144257 41.964085, -94.144257 41.954384, -94.136361 41.954384)) and POLYGON 2:POLYGON((-93.998688 41.883621, -93.998688 41.892822, -94.004525 41.892822, -94.004525 41.883621, -93.998688 41.883621))

Here I add some pics of the issue

















Thank you for your help!
